# How to show path in shell, but only a fixed number from pwd?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell

Basically, I want to display something like:

```
me@host.serv.com:../projects/1234/source$ cd cpp
me@host.serv.com:../1234/source/cpp$
```

instead of:

```
me@host.serv.com:/opt/home/me/dev/projects/1234/source$ cd cpp
me@host.serv.com:/opt/home/me/dev/projects/1234/source/cpp$
```

I've accomplished the second using: `PS1='$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)$ '`, but am unsure how to modify this (or if it's possible for my scenario)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been asked before, with some suggested answers:

- *[trim the terminal command prompt working directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17723/trim-the-terminal-command-prompt-working-directory)* on AskUbuntu
  One suggests setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` (to in turn set `PS1`), using a custom script.  Another says that if you have bash 4.x, that supports a `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` variable (and suggests a workaround for older versions of bash).
- *[How can I shorten my command line (bash) prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145618/how-can-i-shorten-my-command-line-bash-prompt)* on AskUbuntu
  Again, mentioning `PROMPT_DIRTRIM`.

The [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html) describes this, but not in depth:

> PROMPT_DIRTRIM
>
> If set to a number greater than zero, the value is used as the number of trailing directory components to retain when expanding the `\w` and `\W` prompt string escapes (see Controlling the Prompt). Characters removed are replaced with an ellipsis.

Comment: Is there a way to make this carry over to other users when I `sudo su`?

Comment: You could probably set the variable in the bash-specific file which is (often) sourced from `/etc/profile`, which would make it apply by default to all bash users.